# How does one replace characters in a layer name using Python ("_" with " ")?

Tags: arcpy

I can rename layers easily enough, but I really need to replace any "_" with a " ".

This code just renames layers, but I would like to do a find and replace on each layer name

```
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("current")
layers = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd)

for lyr in layers:
    if lyr.name == "X":
        lyr.name = "Y"

arcpy.RefreshTOC()
```

Answer (score 10):

It's pretty much the same code as what you have, but you just need to incorporate the [Python "replace" method](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_replace.htm).  By checking for the existence of the underscore in original name you can avoid needlessly updating every layer name, even if does not have an underscore.

```
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("current")
layers = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd)

for lyr in layers:
    if "_" in lyr.name:
        lyr.name = lyr.name.replace("_", " ")

arcpy.RefreshTOC()
```

Answer (score 4):

I would go for something like this:

```
import arcpy, os, string
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("current")
layers = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd)

for lyr in layers:
    lyrname = str(lyr.name)
    print lyrname
    lyrname_replaced = lyrname.replace("_"," ")
    lyr.name = lyrname_replaced
    print lyrname_replaced

arcpy.RefreshTOC()
```

Comment: No problem. Ryan's code is better because he checks if "_" is in the layer name. Mine doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [.replace](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html) operation.  It should work nicely.  Your code may look something like this.

```
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("current")
layers = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd)

for lyr in layers:
    name = lyr.name
    name = name.replace("_", "")
    lyr.name = name

arcpy.RefreshTOC()
```